# Ошибка в PHP коде [Undefined index}

Tags: php, post

Помогите чайнику

```
Notice: Undefined index: full_name in ... on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: login in ... on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: password in ... on line 12

Notice: Undefined index: password_confirm in ... on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: regional_office in ... on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: position_held in ... on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: email in ... on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: phone in ... on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: status in ... on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: avatar in ... on line 25

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ... on line 25

Notice: Undefined index: avatar in ... on line 26

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in ... on line 26

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...: 14) in ... on line 30

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ... :14) in ... on line 60
```

Сам код

```
<?php
    
    session_start();

    // ...
    require_once 'connect.php';
    
    
    // Получаем данные и фильтруем (удаляем символы html и лишние пробелы) 
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_confirm = $_POST['password_confirm'];
    $regional_office = $_POST['regional_office'];
    $position_held = $_POST['position_held'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    
    
    // Проверка введенного пароля на сходство
    if ($password === $password_confirm) {
        
        // Загрузка изображения
        $path = 'uploads/avatar/' . time() . $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], '../' . $path)) {
            // Уведомление об ошибке загрузки изображения
            $_SESSION['is_error'] = true;
            $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Ошибка загрузки изображения';
            header('Location: ../register.php');
        }
        
        
        // Шифрование пароля пользователя
        $password = md5($password);
        
        
        // Отправка данных
        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `avatar`, `full_name`, `login`, `password`, `regional_office`, `position_held`, `email`, `phone`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, '$full_name', '$login', '$password', '$regional_office', '$position_held', '$email', '$phone', '$status', '$path');");
        
        
        
        /*$store_user = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `avatar`, `full_name`, `login`, `password`, `regional_office`, `position_held`, `email`, `phone`, `status`) VALUES (:path, :full_name, :login, :password, :regional_office, :position_held, :email, :phone, :status)");
        $store_user->execute([
            "path" => $path,
            "email" => $full_name,
            "username" => $login,
            "password" => $password,
            "path" => $regional_office,
            "email" => $position_held,
            "username" => $email,
            "password" => $phone,
            "status" => $status
        ]);*/
        
        
        // Уведомление об успешной регистрации
        $_SESSION['is_success_register'] = true;
        $_SESSION['success_message'] = 'Пользователь зарегистрирован!';
        header('Location: ../register.php');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['is_error'] = true;
        $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'Пароли не совпадают';
        header('Location: ../register.php');
    }
```

Могу включить демонстрацию экрана если понадобится

Comment: Не пришли данные в POST, потому и выдаёт ошибку. Пишите `$_POST['full_name'] ?? null` (PHP 7+), тогда ошибки не будет

Comment: Ошибки исчезли, но данные не пришли и попасть на страницу движка не удается. Я так понимаю  из за правильной работы кода

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/Как-и-какими-средствами-находить-ошибки-в-php-коде